# Mac - iTunes status indicator thing

Tags: macos, user-interface, itunes

I don't know what to call it, but you know that greenish thing covering most of the middle of the top of the iTunes window, that shows the apple symbol or shows the music slider or the status etc., what is it? I've seen several other applications using it -- how do you get it? I couldn't find it in Interface Builder.

Thanks.

Comment: HUD? I don't think it's a standard Cocoa component (yet).

Comment: Then how do these other applications do it? It looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not available as a standard component (yet). iTunes is not even a Cocoa app (well, some part of it is Cocoa, but not much.). A few other Apple apps have similar interface element, so let's hope it'll become available in the next version.